# how to slice values from a group of list?

Tags: python-3.x, list

how to get first value (i.e index 0) of all the list and store it in another list. and second value (i.e index 1) in all list and store in another list and so on.

```
 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: The term you're looking for here is *transpose* which you can do by using zip...

Comment: thank you for pointing this out. it works.

Comment: I assign the list to a, if I call zip(a[0],a[1],a[2]..a[n]) works good. but I call zip(a) doesn't work. I both case I converted to list.

Comment: You need to unpack use zip(*a)

Comment: thank you it worked